# When is next Major UPGRADE file during gitflow development?

Tags: symfony, git-flow

In symfony/symfony project, I see that the master (3.3-dev) exists a file called `UPGRADE-4.0.md`. 4.0 development is not yet started, but this file already exists. What's the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [Symfony release process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html) for details.

4.0 is planned for end of 2017.

The reason why I think you can already check a `upgrade` file for it is to keep track with the planned (breaking) changes to allow to sync your development where possibly required or desired.

E.g. as far as I know given the release strategy 4.0 will require PHP 7 at least - to know something like this already now might help you to adjust as early as possible.

Comment: Is a sort of "take a look of what we will removes in next release"